# Is there any way to attach metadata to HLSL global (uniform/constant) variables?

Tags: directx, direct3d, hlsl, direct3d11

I would like to know if there's any way I can attach application-specific metadata to my global variables in HLSL shaders. I know that HLSL supports [annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509706(v=vs.85).aspx) on global variables, but I can't find any way of reading those annotations (presumably via the reflection API) without using the Effects Framework, which my application doesn't use. Is there any way of attaching application-specific metadata to global variables in HLSL? (Preferably *without* inferring special meaning from the variables' names.)

Use case: I want my application to be able to detect whether a `float4` global is being used as a color or as a simple 4-float vector. In the case where it's a color, the application would display the variable using a color-picker in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the Effects Framework (in D3DX), you can use the [Effects for DX11](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11) library to read the values for these annotations. This is library is not a part of the DirectX SDK itself, and thus, it not specifically deprecated like D3DX. In fact, it's stated intended purpose is:

> Effects 11 is being provided as a porting aid for older code that
>   makes use of the Effects 10 (FX10) API or Effects 9 (FX9) API in the
>   deprecated D3DX9 library. See MSDN for a list of differences compared
>   to the Effects 10 (FX10) library.

Other than annotations, there is no built-in way to attach meta-data to variables, other than with naming schemes (or other such implicit hints).